# Homepage not showing logout in toplink for logged-in customers in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In my local machine, after customer logs-in, homepage is showing logout in the toplink but the same is not happening in live.
In live, when customer logs-in, then homepage behaving as if customer is not logged-in but in any other page, toplink is showing 'logout' option but moving to homepage showing 'login' in the toplink.
I am sure session is maintained because moving to other page is responding correctly but coming to homepage at the same time is showing the issue.

Can anyone please help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several different debugging, I found that I had a CDN service(incapsula) as well installed in my application which I had installed with an aim to prevent DDoS attacks but while having a look to incapsula admin panel, it is found that it also supports caching and incapsula's caching default setting was enabled.
So, for an experiment, what I did is I disabled its caching functionality leaving other functions as is.
That made the trick.

In brief, CDN service "incapsula's" caching ability was the culprit in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a cache issue.
If you have a custom block showing these links that may be a missing `isLoggedIn()` key in getCacheKeyInfo() function.

Comment: can you please tell me any approx. location where it may be present?

Comment: I am working on staging server which is an instance of live..
My doubt is, isn't this happening because homepage of staging is considering as the homepage of live..
I am using nginx.. 
Please let me know if you have any idea in this?

Comment: Can you please tell me some way to resolve this issue.

Comment: In Magento Blocks you have a function named `getCacheKeyInfo()` which is used to construt the unique key of a cache. It is an array of value. In your case, if you have a custom block, that is maybe because this function is missing the `isLoggedIn()` customer information.

Comment: In your staging environment can you disable all caches and check if the issue is still here ? If disabling the caches the error disapear, this is a cache issue.

Comment: Now, this is happening in live..I disabled all the magento cache and checked but no luck.
When logged-in customer is coming to homepage using the logo or by manually tying home url, 'logout' toplink is not showing instead 'login' is showing but when the user is moving to any other link then it is fine showing 'logout' link in toplink..
NOTE: In homepage, when I am typing https://homepageurl, then also it is absolutely fine. Only incase of http, homepage showing this issue
Note: I am using Varnish for frontend caching

Please help!

Comment: In this case this look like a Varnish issue. Contact your hosting company to see if there is no issue with the environment `.vcl` file.

Comment: you were correct that its a cache issue. But normally, we use to have varnish/FPC as a caching service but in mycase, Incapsula was the culprit who was caching in addition.
Thanks for your time

Comment: OK no problem glad yo help ;) Can you accept my answer or vote up to validate the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @ Matthéo Geoffray: I marked you up but just because what I mentioned was the exact case mentioned, so marked it as accepted!